# how to add vertical scroll bars in tabcontrol/tabpages

Tags: c#, winforms

I am designing an application in which i am using tab-control, and in one of the tab-page the information i want to display in bigger than the form size, the information is displayed in various text-boxes. i tried by adding following lines in designer code but it is still not working.

```
this.AutoScroll = true;
this.AutoScrollMargin = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
this.AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height);
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to set the `AutoScroll` on the `TabPage`, not the `Form`, you can do this at design time by **selecting your tabpage first, then set the AutoScroll to true in the Properties window**, or you can do by code like this:

```
 tabPage1.AutoScroll = true;
 //do the same for other tabPages
```

Answer (score 5):

Notice that "this" refer to whole class (your form).

Increase the value like this:

```
tab.AutoScrollMinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1000,1000);
```

Or you can add `panel1` to your tab, then dock it into the tab:

```
panel1.dock = dockingSyle.Fill;
```

Now you can make `panel1` scrollable.

Comment: For some reason I had to set `AutoScrollMinSize`. Whyever.

Comment: If you use dockingSyle.Fill the panel will fit the tabpage and you won't see the scroolbars. I think a better solution would be dockingSyle.Top, where you can specify only the height (even graphically). If the panel is taller than the tabpage (with AutoScroll=true) you will see the scrollbar.